# Searching a in multimap for a range of keys

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am programming a College Library system.
as books \ magazine database I using a map that the key is the Item ID number
(1000000 - 99999999) and the value is a pointer to the item object.

each item related to one of 7 existing faculties on the collage and this is how the key of the item is set.
the first digit is the faculty number ( 1 -7) and the rest of the number is 0
000000X (when x is a number relative to the items size)

my question is can I get how many keys are stating with the number 
(1 - 7) so I will know how many are in the specific faculty.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::equal_range`.

Comment: Without changing the structure there is no faster solution than O(N). If you had a sorted vector instead of a map, you could use binary search for a O(logN) solution. Or add another multimap keyed on the first digit.

Comment: "_the first digit is the faculty number (1 -7)_" - but the range of ID numbers is `[1000000, 99999999]`, so what about ID numbers starting with 8 or 9?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I miss some point here. But normally you can simply use `std::count_if` to count.

I hope I understood you question correctly.

Here is one of many possible solutions:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct TestItem
{
    int id{ 0 };
} testItemObject;

int main()
{
    // Define a multimap with testdata  
    std::multimap<std::string, TestItem*> testMM{ {"1000000", &testItemObject},
        {"2000000", &testItemObject},{"2000001", &testItemObject},
        {"3000000", &testItemObject},{"3000001", &testItemObject},{"3000002", &testItemObject},
        {"4000000", &testItemObject},{"4000001", &testItemObject},{"4000002", &testItemObject},{"4000003", &testItemObject},
        {"5000000", &testItemObject},{"5000001", &testItemObject},{"5000002", &testItemObject},{"5000003", &testItemObject},{"5000004", &testItemObject},
        {"6000000", &testItemObject},{"6000001", &testItemObject},{"6000002", &testItemObject},{"6000003", &testItemObject},{"6000004", &testItemObject},{"6000005", &testItemObject},
        {"7000000", &testItemObject},{"7000001", &testItemObject},{"7000002", &testItemObject},{"7000003", &testItemObject},{"7000004", &testItemObject},{"7000005", &testItemObject},{"7000006", &testItemObject},
        {"8000000", &testItemObject},{"8000001", &testItemObject},{"8000002", &testItemObject},{"8000003", &testItemObject},{"8000004", &testItemObject},{"8000005", &testItemObject},{"8000006", &testItemObject},{"8000007", &testItemObject},
        {"9000000", &testItemObject},{"9000001", &testItemObject},{"9000004", &testItemObject},{"9000003", &testItemObject},{"9000004", &testItemObject},{"9000005", &testItemObject},{"9000006", &testItemObject},{"9000007", &testItemObject},{"9000008", &testItemObject},
    };

    // We want to look for keys starting with
    std::vector<char> firstLetterToSearch{ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

    // Using std::count_if to count
    std::for_each(firstLetterToSearch.begin(), firstLetterToSearch.end(),
        [&testMM](const char c) { 
            std::cout << c << " --> " << 
                std::count_if(testMM.begin(), testMM.end(), [&c](std::pair<const std::string, TestItem*> & mm) { return mm.first[0] == c; }) 
                << "\n"; 
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```